# How to Fix this error in video Event fx on sony vegas 8 pro?

Tags: video, youtube, adobe, sony, video-editing

When i move the cursor in video event fx block. The video is not showing real time view. I want to see the real time video view so that i can move that object to suitable position.
watch the video to know about the error -
Sorry for grammar errors.
Video URL - https://www.dropbox.com/s/df8vk90crzphq16/ice_video_20160308-193717.webm?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

improve your PC specifications specially the graphic card.